# Is my solution consider as a proof of inclusion-exclusion for $k=3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is my solution but I don't know if I can consider it as proof???
Here let $A$ , $B$ , and $C$ are sets

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is perfect as long as you know the justification for each step. You may also want to try using induction to prove the general case for $n$ sets.

Comment: Induction is the last thing you want to use here.

Comment: @LeonAragones: What are you talking about? There is a relatively easy proof of the general Inclusion-Exclusion Principle using just induction on the number of sets. There is also another proof using binary but it relies ultimately on induction as well. In a technical sense it is impossible to prove the general principle without induction.

Comment: if I had to guess, I'm guessing user207868 is referring to some counting proof. For example,  see https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/InclusionExclusion.shtml where some counting arguments are paired with an application of the binomial theorem to prove it. That said, I find the induction proof more fulfilling.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook: It doesn't matter what user207868 was referring to, because it is wrong. As I said, "In a technical sense it is **impossible** to prove the general principle without induction.". If you are familiar with logic it should be obvious.